# How can I use AJAX to bring bring pdfs into a div?

Tags: html, ajax

Okay, in my first jump into AJAX-like behavior...

I'm wanting to load a div with a pdf based on a user click on a link.  If the user clicks on a second link, the div should be overwritten with the new pdf.

So I figured on testing it with something like:

```
<script>
    function showPdf()
    {
        var pdfDiv = document.getElementById("pdfDiv");
        pdfDiv.innerHTML='<object type="application/pdf" data="my.pdf" width="500" height="650" ></object>';
    }
</script>
<div id="pdfDiv"></div>
```

This, however, does not work.

I'm guessing I'm probably setting the innerHTML, but it's not actually fetching the file.  I figure I need some AJAXy knowledge to force that new request after the page has loaded.  Can someone point me to the right object to start exploring?

Comment: Is the path correct? Does `my.pdf` exist on the same directory level?

Comment: @Pekka: That's just a fake filename.  For the real one I'm using an absolute path like "/topdir/middledir/bottomdir/my.pdf".

Comment: "/topdir/middledir..." being an absolute path to a  web resource that works when you open it directly in your browser, right? (Just to make sure.)

Comment: @Pekka: Good thinking...always double check assumptions.  Yep, it shows up fine if I just paste it into the URL field.

Comment: Hmm. And if you insert the `object` tag as pure HTML, it works as expected?

Answer (score 2):

You could try and use something like [this](http://www.ajaxonomy.com/2008/web-design/web-based-pdf-viewer)...

Answer (score 2):

I'd try something easier: use Google PDF Viewer service. You just have to create an iframe and change its src:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: This won't work for me, since our corporate site probably doesn't want to rely on an external service.  However, I've voted this up because I think it would be useful for a lot of people.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using an iframe? Doesn't the whole "document" need to be the PDF url?

Comment: Why? He's using an `<object>`. No need for an iFrame per se.

Comment: Haven't tried using an iframe...don't think it should be necessary.  (but then again, I don't know much about this, yet.)